# Количество строк перенесенных по словам текста в TextBox

Tags: c#

**Проблема:**

Поставил у TextBox параметры **`Multiline = true;`** и **`WordWrap = true;`**. Всё отлично, переносит, но я не понимаю: *как узнать количество строк, в которые текст мой влезает с заданными параметрами ширины*

---

**p.s. Основная задача**

При изменении текста подгонять высоту у TextBox под необходимые размеры.

Comment: как насчёт подсчета количества знаков переноса в строке?

Comment: @Сахарок как вариант, но не уверен что эти символы будут в строке которая просто перенеслась по Multiline и WordWrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не самая приятная задача, если честно...

В своё время решалось через [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/957webty.aspx)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую :)

Comment: попробовал, слишком тяжело получается... В результате решил основную задачу без подсчета кол-ва строк, с помощью метода **`GetPreferredSize`**

Answer (score 2):

Нашел один метод, который решает мою проблему:

```
        this.textBox1.TextChanged += delegate
        {
            Size oldSize = this.textBox1.Size;
            Size newSize = textBox1.GetPreferredSize(oldSize);
            this.textBox1.Height = newSize.Height;
        };
```

Comment: В случае с элементом управления, да, вполне подходящее решение, не сообразил :) Не ищу лёгких путей, но у меня задача ставилась для кастомного элемента управления, так что было много хуже.

Comment: @Spawn: В таком случае, вероятно, лучшим решением будет WPF и его layout manager...

Comment: @VladD, я тоже большой сторонник WPF, но, увы, и под WinForms приходится что-то делать